# Formula para tranformar Minnutos em Dias/Horas/Minutos/Segundos

Tags: microsoft-excel

Como que eu posso fazer uma formula para transformar minutos em Dias/Horas/Minutos/Segundos mas não sai da estaca 0 já tentei de varias maneiras mas não estou conseguindo.

```
O valor em minutos é: 7188,15
=INT(D8/60/24) *isso me da o dia 4 dias inteiro
=(D9/60/24-E9)*24 *isso me da as 23,80 horas
```

O problema e que eu gostaria de deixar todos os valores na mesma célula como 4d 23h 50m 33s
e não estou conseguindo achar uma formula que faça isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui chegar à uma fórmula utilizando as fórmulas de `QUOCIENTE` que calcula a divisão inteira de uma divisão, e a fórmula `MOD` que retorna o resto da divisão inteira.

## Dia

Para calcular as horas, utilizamos a função `QUOCIENTE` com o tempo em minutos no numerador e o valor de **1440** (quantidade de minutos em 1 dia) no denominador, retornando a divisão inteira dos minutos totais e a quantidade de minutos em um dia:

```
=QUOCIENTE(A1;1440)
```

## Hora

Para calcular as horas, utilizamos novamente a função `QUOCIENTE`, onde no numerador vai a função `MOD`, retornando o resto da divisão inteira dos dias e o valor **60** no denominador, que equivale à quantidade de minutos em uma hora:

```
=QUOCIENTE(MOD(A1;1440);60)
```

## Minuto

Para calcular os minutos, calculamos o valor inteiro do resto da divisão entre o resto da divisão dos dias com o valor **60**:

```
=INT(MOD(MOD(A1;1440);60))
```

## Segundo

Por fim, para calcular os segundos, utilizamos o valor total de minutos menos o valor inteiro de total de minutos para obtermos somente os números após as casas decimais, que equivalem aos segundos, depois é só multiplicar por 60 segundos:

```
=INT((A1-INT(A1))*60)
```

Depois disso é só juntar tudo.

A fórmula completa fica assim, onde `A1` é a sua célula onde irá colocar o numero em minutos para calcular o tempo.

```
=QUOCIENTE(A1;1440)&"d "&QUOCIENTE(MOD(A1;1440);60)&"h "&INT(MOD(MOD(A1;1440);60))&"m " &INT((A1-INT(A1))*60) & "s"
```

Veja mais sobre a função [MOD](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mod-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) e [QUOCIENTE](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/quociente-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-quociente-9f7bf099-2a18-4282-8fa4-65290cc99dee)

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou muito bem, e obrigado pela explicação detalhada.